# ASIO Client Server Connects Fine on the same PC, but Fails across a Local Network

Tags: c++, networking, tcp, server, boost-asio

I'm going to include all the relevant portions of code, but I'm pretty sure the problem is with my network, not with my code, since my code works perfectly fine if I loopback on a single computer. Nevertheless, if you see any immediately obvious errors in the code, I'd like to know.

Reference `basic_server` code (only the relevant parts):

```
connection_id basic_server::start_listening(const std::string & ip_address, const std::string & port) {
    asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(*service);
    asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query(ip_address, port);
    asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint = *(resolver.resolve(query));

    connection_id id(get_seed());
    while (connections.contains(id)) {
        std::this_thread::yield();
        id = get_seed();
    }
    connections[id] = connection_ptr(new connection(id, *service, ip_address, port));
    connection_ptr conn = connections[id];
    conn->state = listening;

    if (!acceptor->is_open()) {
        acceptor->open(endpoint.protocol());
    }
    if (current_ip != ip_address || current_port != port) {
        acceptor->bind(endpoint);
        current_ip = ip_address;
        current_port = port;
    }
    acceptor->listen(asio::socket_base::max_connections);

    acceptor->async_accept(
        conn->get_socket(),
        std::bind(
            &basic_server::connect,
            this,
            std::placeholders::_1,
            id
        )
    );
    return id;
}

connection_id basic_server::start_connecting(const std::string & ip_address, const std::string & port) {
    asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(*service);
    asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query(ip_address, port);
    asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint = *(resolver.resolve(query));

    connection_id id(get_seed());
    while (connections.contains(id)) {
        std::this_thread::yield();
        id = get_seed();
    }
    connections[id] = connection_ptr(new connection(id, *service, ip_address, port));
    connection_ptr conn = connections[id];
    conn->state = connecting;

    conn->get_socket().async_connect(
        endpoint,
        std::bind(
            &basic_server::connect,
            this,
            std::placeholders::_1,
            id
        )
    );
    return id;
}
```

Reference Server code:

```
#include "../../Utilities/BasicServer/Basic Server.h"

int main() {
    server::basic_server this_server;
    server::connection_id id = this_server.start_listening("::1", "6118");
    const std::set<server::connection_state> valid_states = { server::open, server::listening, server::connecting };
    while (this_server.connection_status(id) == server::listening) std::cout << "Waiting for Client.\r";
    std::cout << std::endl;
    while (true) {
        if (valid_states.find(this_server.connection_status(id)) == valid_states.end()) {
            std::cout << "We've lost connection with the client." << std::endl;
            break;
        }
        server::data_pair data;
        bool successful_read = this_server.read_from_queue(data);
        if (!successful_read) {
            std::this_thread::yield();
            continue;
        }
        server::connection_id read_id = data.first;
        server::data_vector & read_vector = data.second;
        std::string line;
        line.resize(70);
        std::copy(read_vector.begin(), read_vector.begin() + std::min(70ull, read_vector.size()), line.begin());
        std::cout << line << std::endl;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Reference Client Code (not much different from the Server code):

```
#include "../../Utilities/BasicServer/Basic Server.h"

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    server::basic_server this_client;
    std::string ip_address;
    if (argc < 2) return 0;
    ip_address = argv[1];
    server::connection_id id = this_client.start_connecting(ip_address, "6118");
    const std::set<server::connection_state> valid_states = { server::open, server::listening, server::connecting };
    while (this_client.connection_status(id) == server::connecting) std::cout << "Connecting to Server with IP address \"" << ip_address << "\"\r";
    std::cout << std::endl;
    if (this_client.connection_status(id) == server::open) {
        std::cout << "We're connected!" << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Unable to connect." << std::endl;
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
    while (true) {
        if (valid_states.find(this_client.connection_status(id)) == valid_states.end()) {
            std::cout << "We've lost connection." << std::endl;
            break;
        }
        std::string line;
        std::getline(std::cin, line);
        std::cout << "Attemping to write \"" << line << "\"" << std::endl;
        this_client.write_to_connection(id, &line.front(), line.size() * sizeof(unsigned char));
        if (line == "") break;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

So the basic gist of my problem is that when I try to connect from one computer to another (via my local network) the connection fails. If I run the server and client on the same computer, it works with no problems. I've tried all of the following:

- pinging the receiving/sending computers to verify they see each other: they do.
- running `tracert` to check the connection: they reach each other in one hop, no outside connections involved.
- swapping between using IPv6 and IPv4 (my router supports both) to attempt to connect: I determined that when looping back, using IPv6 as the server binding endpoint won't work if the client uses the IPv4 loopback address, and vice-versa, but if they're both using IPv6 or IPv4 it works fine on the loopback. None of these work across different computers.

Any thoughts as to what's going wrong?

Comment: Your server is listening only localhost: `start_listening("::1", "6118");`. Is it the bug?

Comment: @psialt How would I specify that I want to listen to connections from anywhere, not just locally?

Comment: in this case you should listen `0.0.0.0` or if you create an endpoint `ip::tcp::endpoint( ip::tcp::v4(), 6118 )`

Comment: @PSIAlt If I intend to listen to connections on both IPv4 and IPv6, do I need to bind to two endpoints?

Comment: @PSIAlt Also, I've tested this solution, and it doesn't solve the problem. I can still connect via loopback, but nothing works across different machines.

Comment: what about firewall? Can you try telnet on this port? tcpdump traffic?

Comment: @PSIAlt Okay, I've tested this solution on a different network and it worked. The loopback address failed on both networks, but the 0.0.0.0 endpoint worked on my home network. The useful indicator here was the fact that on my home network, using endpoint 0.0.0.0 prompted a Firewall notification, and after accepting it, the program worked. So if you want to post this as an answer, I'll upvote it and accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we found in the comments, the problem was network firewall plus listening localhost only. Listening on any IP is available when you listen `0.0.0.0` IP or if you use **endpoint**, create it without specifying listen IP address: `ip::tcp::endpoint( ip::tcp::v4(), 6118 )`